# asyncData() or fetch() does not work async, but in mounted it works correctly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm enough. I spent a few hours, but cant figure out how it works. My code works in SPA by the mounted() hook, but I migrate to nuxt now and faced with problems.

I'm trying to get data from store by asyncData()

```
async asyncData({store}) {
console.log("start getting schools")
const schools = await store.dispatch('GET_SCHOOLS_FROM_API').then((schools) => {
  console.log(schools)
})
console.log(schools + " schools")     
return schools
 },
```

or fetch()

```
async fetch({store}) {
const sch = await store.dispatch('GET_SCHOOLS_FROM_API')
  this.schools = store.SCHOOLS; //SCHOOLS is a getter in store  
});
},
```

but it does not wait for dispatch to complete and returns undefind.

store:

```
async GET_SCHOOLS_FROM_API({ commit }) {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/schools').then((schools) => {
        commit('SET_SCHOOLS_TO_STATE', schools.data)
        return schools;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    })
}
```

does somebody have an idea where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing was, that I did not remove data() from a component, and it was a mistake. After that, the code above works correctly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are intersecting the `Promise` with an additional `then` block, when you add the `await` you are actually waiting for the result of the promise inserted in the then block, there you have a function that doesn't return anything, hence it returns `undefined`.

This can be easily fixed like:

```
async asyncData({ store }) {
    console.log("start getting schools");
    const schools = await store.dispatch('GET_SCHOOLS_FROM_API');
    console.log(schools);
    
    return { schools };
}
```

Another thing is that according to the example in the docs they return the value as an object, can you try that?

**Ref** https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $http }) {
      const post = await $http.$get(`https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/${params.id}`)
      return { post } // <===== Like this
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but I started from this way and it does not work :(

Comment: Thanks, again. Yes, Daniel, I have read the documentation and try it. But here is the thing, that code works asynchronically, and return { result } = return undefined. After component rendered, I can see SCHOOLS in vuedev tools.